# Import/Export Recipe in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchard-modules

I have been facing many issues whenever I try to import the changes. 
We have three orchard instances for different environments. Changes made in one should be migrated to remaining two instances. For this, I am using import/export module in orchard CMS(v 1.6.0.0).

The export file contains only the changes I made in CMS1 => CMS1.xml and those which are already there are deleted from the file. If I update Resource text ie., "Export Untouched" to "Export Modified" and save changes to the XML file, then when I import this file to CMS2 and CMS3 instances, those imports are not working.

NOTE:  I did not change the Key, I just updated the value.

[image: Orchard CMS Recipe]

[image: App_Data]

***Exception:***

```
thread:[11] ERROR - NullReferenceException thrown from <>f__AnonymousType4`2 by <>f__AnonymousType4`2
[[Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],
[Orchard.ContentPicker.Fields.ContentPickerField, Orchard.ContentPicker, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] 
server: XXX.YYY.com operation : /XXXCMS/Admin/ImportExport/Export exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.GetItemMetadata(IContent content) in d:\Builds\29\XXX\MP_2_0_XXXCMS_Support\Sources\XXX\Main\Source\Webs\Webx\XXXX_YYYYY2.0\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 513 at Orchard.ContentPicker.Drivers.ContentPickerFieldDriver.<Exporting>b__13(ContentItem x) at System.Linq.Enumerable.
<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1.
.ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Orchard.ContentPicker.Drivers.ContentPickerFieldDriver.Exporting(ContentPart part, ContentPickerField field, ExportContentContext context) at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentFieldDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.IContentFieldDriver.Exporting>b__1b(ContentPart part, TField field) 
in d:\Builds\29\XXX\MP_2_0_XXXCMS_Support\Sources\XXX\Main\Source\Webs\Webx\XXX2.0\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentFieldDriver.cs:line 67 at
Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentFieldDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass25.<Process>b__23(<>f__AnonymousType4`2 pf) in
d:\Builds\29\XXX\MP_2_0_XXXCMS_Support\Sources\XXX\Main\Source\Webs\Webx\XXXX_YYYY2.0\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentFieldDriver.cs:line 80 at
Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in d:\Builds\29\XXX\MP_2_0_XXXX_Support\Sources\XXX\Main\Source\Webs\Webx\Project 2.0\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
```

[image]

Comment: Anything in error logs?

Comment: Well m not sure where logs are stored. I checked in database, but didnot find any tables related to logging.

Comment: In `App_data/logs`.

Comment: I dont have logs in that location. Attached Screenshot.

Comment: That's weird. Another thing you can try is to attach a debugger, and put breakpoints in `ContentFieldDriver.Importing` and `Exporting`. See if those get hit. Also, break on exceptions, see if you hit any.

Comment: I actually found an exception logged( at a place for all exceptions on the site) when i tried to do the export. 
Attached to the question!!

Comment: Thanks. So the problem happens during export, and to figure it out exactly, attaching a debugger would help. There's one thing that seems suspicious: the stack trace has `ContentPickerFieldDriver`, but I don't see a content picker field on that content. Do you have an idea what could explain that? Can you share the content type definition?

Comment: I think the issue is not with export file, coz, export file contains what i need. When trying to import, it is throwing "No loader found for extension "Contrib.UpdateContent"!" exception.

Comment: I see something "UpdateContent" in the Website under Module

Comment: Do you need it? Also, can you share the content type definition like I asked?

Comment: That's not the content type definition. Go to the admin, find content type definitions in the menu, find your type and tell me what you see.

Comment: attached to the question.

Comment: Do you need that update content extension?

Comment: I dont need it. It is any way in disabled state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144661/discussion-between-priya-payyavula-and-bertrand-le-roy).

Comment: Even if disabled, it can still cause problems because it will still be compiled and loaded, and this seems to fail. Try to delete its directory.